# Kademi - how to set canonicals on a product page

Tags: kademi

I am trying to set a canonical on a product detail page to prevent duplicate pages of the same URL.

Our client's website has 1375 however search engines are picking up 2890 because the overwhelming majority of pages are being rendered as duplicate such as the below several examples.

Same product example 1:

```
https://www.waterware.co.nz/store/1-function-hand-shower
https://www.waterware.co.nz/store/FW556
```

Same product example 2:

```
https://www.waterware.co.nz/store/1-function-hand-shower-black
https://www.waterware.co.nz/store/FW550BL
```

Same product example 3:

```
https://www.waterware.co.nz/store/1-2m-shower-hose-metal-wound
https://www.waterware.co.nz/store/FH112SS
```

And repeat 1375x.

I have since discovered where the 2nd version of the URL is coming from - its the favourites icon on product detail page - and will begin removing / adjusting these.

However in order to maintain best SEO practices I need to find a way to set a canonical.

I am aware that this could be done MasterTemplate.html. However there does not seem to be a way to discover the correct scope when in the master template file.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SEO integration was commented out in KCommerce2, but it will be re-enabled in the next release later this week

This uses the webname property in the canonical href.

It also inserts the meta description field using the brief if its available, otherwise the product body.

And it also generates a meta keywords tag, using the product code, categories and brand.

To use this once available, you will just need to update to KCommerce 3.1.3 or later.